# Z-Rotation in webgl

Tags: javascript, webgl, rotational-matrices

I was taught that counterclockwise rotation is in the positive direction.

but z-rotation matrix works in reverse.

And the transition matrix needs to be inverted to work normally.

It is correct?

This is part of code.

```
translationMatrix =[
            1,0,0,0,
            0,1,0,0,
            0,0,1,0,
            Tx,Ty,Tz,1
         ];
var translation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "translation");
         gl.uniformMatrix4fv(translation, false, flatten(translationMatrix));

}
...

else if(z1){
ztheta+=0.1;
zr1=false;
}

else if(z2){
ztheta-=0.1;
zr2=false;
}
...

zrotationMatrix =[
            Math.cos(ztheta),-Math.sin(ztheta),0,0,
            Math.sin(ztheta),Math.cos(ztheta),0,0,
            0,0,1,0,
            0,0,0,1
         ];

var rotationz=gl.getUniformLocation(program, "rotationz");  
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(rotationz, false, flatten(zrotationMatrix));

...
  void main() {
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix*rotationz*rotationy*rotationx*scaler*translation* vPosition
;
      }
```